# Windows won't boot after moving house. How do I solve this?

Tags: windows-7, boot, uefi

Ive just moved house and tried to set up my desktop after packing it away and now when I power it on, the BIOS boots up and no errors are found but when my computer tires to boot into Windows 7 a continuous fast beeping sound is made and a black screen is displayed.

What I've done so far:

- Reset to UEFI defauts
- Played about with RAM, I had 4*4 GB sticks, I took all of them out to test for a mobo error which I have and now im only using 1 stick of 4 GB.
- Changed my GPU, I tok my gtx580 out and now im using the onboard Intel 3000 graphics driver, the BIOS and uefi are correctly displaying so I no longer think its a GPU based error.
- Ive check all of the connections and nothing seems to be loose.

My HDD setup is:

- 2 128 GB SSD's in Raid 0 as my main C drive (possibly cause of error?)
- 1 1 TB Games drive
- 1 2 TB Data Drive

Ive also got a blueray drive connected.

After searching the internet im pretty much out of suggestions but im currently downloading a live CD to see if it will boot and if I can access some files on my HDD.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference to the continuous beeping sound on the AsRock z68 extreme 4 motherboard after the BIOS. The problem was that my boot partion wasn’t configured correctly in the UEFI under the RAID settings. And so my computer couldn’t find the file to boot into. The only thing puzzeling me is how in the trip moving house the setting got changed...

Answer (score 1):

> a continuous fast beeping sound is made

Have a look at your motherboard manual. There should be a table which shows what those beeps could mean.

In addition, I recommend to boot your system with a Linux Live CD.